# How to remove book cover fold on Google Books API image covers

Tags: google-books, google-books-api

When searching the Google Books API with a basic title search query like [this](https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=trillion+dollar+coach) (trillion dollar coach), the results return images that look like the following:

[image]

*(Notice the page fold at the bottom right of the image)*

Does anyone know how to get book covers that never have a fold? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Someone had recommended using the endpoint below instead, which gets more options and higher quality images for the cover. Although it still shows a small page cover at the bottom right.          http://books.google.com/books/publisher/content?id=nmdzDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=6&edge=curl&imgtk=AFLRE72wKAhJWgbo1FdsU1J9-qObkPV-BLTp92b3F75iEzhSR2f4Icif7jZvqrlN4H8mZTGDXemBzgSUGR6ZABUEpCSf71r2LKk5P6YuBFNJRwG9YDF1dvWtVeMaCv0FHkKmhj8J-Qu8&source=gbs_api

Comment: Simply remove the "&edge=curl" part from the image URL.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Page-curl variable from the image link

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).